# Weird Functions Calling and Inconsistent Result

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, authentication, pycharm

First, I just want to say I'm a newbie, and I apologize for the bad explanation and the long post...

So, as a practice, I wrote a simple python login system with a JSON file where the profiles are stored.

Everything was going well, but all of a sudden my code started behaving weirdly.
this is my main.py file:

```
import json

with open("profiles.json") as f:
    profiles = json.load(f)


def main():
    print("-----------------Main--------------------")
    option = input("[L]ogin | [S]ign up: ").upper()

    if option == "L":
        login()
    elif option == "S":
        sign_up()
    else:
        print("Please select a valid option.")
        main()


def login():
    print("-----------------Login--------------------")

    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    check_credentials(username, password)


def sign_up():
    print("-----------------Sign up--------------------")

    new_username = None
    new_password = None

    # check if this username already exists, return to sign up if true
    def username_match():
        nonlocal new_username

        new_username = input("Username: ")

        for profile in profiles["profiles"]:
            if new_username == profile["username"]:
                print("This username is taken.")
                username_match()

    # loop back if the passwords do not match
    def password_match():
        nonlocal new_password

        new_password = input("Password: ")
        confirm_password = input("Confirm Password: ")

        if new_password != confirm_password:
            print("Passwords do not match.")
            password_match()

    username_match()
    password_match()

    security_question = input("Security Question: ")
    security_answer = input("Security Question Answer: ")

    profiles["profiles"].append({"username": new_username,
                                 "password": new_password,
                                 "security_question": security_question,
                                 "security_answer": security_answer})

    with open("profiles.json", "w") as w:
        json.dump(profiles, w, indent=2)

    check_credentials(new_username, new_password)


def profile_settings():
    input("-----------------Options--------------------"
          "\n"
          "[P] change password | [U] change username"
          "\n"
          "[S] change security question | [E] add email"
          "\n"
          "What would you like to do: ").upper()

    print("\nThis section is under construction. Please visit later.")


def check_credentials(username, password):
    print("\nchecking credentials...\n")

    for profile in profiles["profiles"]:

        if profile["username"] != username and profile["password"] != password:
            print("Wrong username and password, please try again.")
            login()

        if profile["username"] == username:
            print(f"found username: {username}")
            if profile["password"] == password:
                print(f"found password: {password}")
            else:
                print("Wrong password, please try again.")
                login()
        else:
            print("Wrong username, please try again.")
            login()

        profile_settings()


main()
```

and this is my profiles.json file:

```
{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "username": "Hakobu",
      "password": "123",
      "security_question": "favorite food",
      "security_answer": "lemon"
    },
    {
      "username": "Mohammed",
      "password": "345",
      "security_question": "1",
      "security_answer": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what I found weird:

1. When I try to login to a second profile, it tells me, wrong credentials and put me back to the `login()` function, but it lets me in for the first profile.
2. when trying to make a new profile through the `sign_up()` function, it is supposed to automatically log in but beyond the first profile, the second profile created just does the same thing, it tells me, wrong credentials and put me back to the `login()` function.
3. when successfully logging in with the first profile, the `profile_settings()` function gets called. it's supposed to close after inputing anything, but instead it goes back to the `check_credentials()` function, says I input the wrong username and password, then going to the `login()` function straight after the `profile_settings()` function even though I have not called them anywhere in the `profile_settings()` function

I have no idea why in god's name this happens. It was working fine just a little bit ago. Tried commenting out the code I wrote after it was working but nothing worked. I have a huge headache now and my back hurts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning about stack calls and stack frames, I now know that the issue was simply the for loop getting resumed after exiting the `check_credentials()` resulting in what seemed to be an infinite loop of that function.

Here is the improved code:

```
def check_credentials(username, password):
    print("\nchecking credentials...\n")

    username_found = False
    password_found = False

    for profile in profiles["profiles"]:
        if profile["username"] == username:
            print(f"found username: {username}")
            username_found = True
            if profile["password"] == password:
                print(f"found password: {password}")
                password_found = True
                break

    if not username_found and not password_found:
        print("Wrong username and password, please try again.")
        login()
    elif not username_found:
        print("Wrong username, please try again.")
        login()
    elif not password_found:
        print("Wrong password, please try again.")
        login()

    profile_settings()
```